# Website is different between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, performance, mobile-website, responsive-images

I just found out that if I navigate on my
[website](https://allevamentobarboncinimaatilayla.it/) with iOS (iphone and ipad) it shows me this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9scRZ.jpg

While if I open it with Android it shows me this one (that is the correct one) -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW3VR.jpg

All the images, in different pages, that are as background, have this problem (on iphone), the same for the footer that has a background image too. 
It's like if on iPhone all the background images are **super zoomed**.

I deleted the cache, I checked all my CSS code and I tried to change pictures, nothing happened.

What else can I do?
Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could behave differently. Since, we could write different css based on resolution or user-agent (safari for ios, chrome for android).

Comment: I tried Chrome and Mozilla Firefox on iOS too but the problem is still there. I also tried Bing instead of Google, nothing changed.

Comment: Did you use any JS to load image dynamically? Then could be JS disable in your IOS phone; 

I see it working with responsive checker but seems for some width you need small css fix
https://imgur.com/a/XX9Tv7s

Comment: How can I check? I checked on iPhones and iPads (not mines) and there is the same problem...Yes, I know about the width bad CSS on small devices but for now I want to understand why iOS devices give me this problem.